# Android GPS Status driving me nuts

Tags: android, gps

I am making a application that uses the GPS receiver. The application will work on all versions starting from 1.6. I have a satellite Icon in which I tell the users the current status:

> - if icon is red - gps disabled
> - if icon is orange - gps is enabled and trying to fix on the satellites
> - if icon is green - gps is fixed and running fine.

After reading around here, I've found that some events for onLocationChanged trigger on 1.6 version but not later, so taking the advice I implemented a GPS listener. I have some really weird behavior as the status of the icon gets messed out. For instance I enable GPS and gets orange... after a fix get's green.. after a few seconds gets read after a second orange and so on...

Here is the code I use. Please suggest what to change

```
public class TrackExecutionActivity extends Activity{

protected static final long GPS_UPDATE_TIME_INTERVAL=3000;  //millis
protected static final float GPS_UPDATE_DISTANCE_INTERVAL=0; //meters
private LocationManager mlocManager;
private MyGPSListener mGpsListener;
private LocationListener mlocListener; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.trackexecution);

        imgGpsState = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgGpsState);
        mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
        mGpsListener = new MyGPSListener();
}

private class MyGPSListener implements GpsStatus.Listener {
        public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
            boolean isGPSFix = false;
            switch (event) {
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
                    if (mLastLocation != null)
                        isGPSFix = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastLocationMillis) < GPS_UPDATE_TIME_INTERVAL * 2;

                    if (isGPSFix) { // A fix has been acquired.
                        imgGpsState.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gps_on_green));
                    } else { // The fix has been lost.
                        imgGpsState.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gps_on_orange));
                    }

                    break;

                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
                    imgGpsState.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gps_on_green));
                    break;
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
                    imgGpsState.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gps_on_orange));
                    break;
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
                    imgGpsState.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gps_on_red));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            if (location != null) {
                       mLastLocationMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            // do some things here
                     mLastLocation = location;

        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
        { 
            imgGpsState.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gps_on_red));
        } 

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
        { 
            imgGpsState.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gps_on_orange));
        } 

        //this doesn't trigger on Android 2.x users say
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
        { 
        }
        }
        }

 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
     if(mlocManager != null) {
         if (mGpsListener == null)
         {
            mGpsListener = new MyGPSListener();
         }

         if (mlocListener == null)
         {
            mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
         }

        mlocManager.addGpsStatusListener(mGpsListener);
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, GPS_UPDATE_TIME_INTERVAL, GPS_UPDATE_DISTANCE_INTERVAL, mlocListener);
      }
       super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change this:

```
isGPSFix = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastLocationMillis) < GPS_UPDATE_TIME_INTERVAL * 2;
```

your are setting a boolean with non boolean values.. hence the weird icon behavior during gps fixes you need to set that `isGPSfix` boolean somewhere.. for case of `hasGPSfix` or `doesnothaveGPSfix`..

You might have meant:

```
if ((SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastLocationMillis) < GPS_UPDATE_TIME_INTERVAL * 2) {
    isGPSFIX = true;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a dream. Interesting, I wouldn't have thought to that. Thank you for your help.